# Calendar android value of HOUR/MINUTE

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, listener

i have a problem with my calendar...
When i choice a hour between 01 and 09 , in my field , it's write the hour whithin "0" , like if i choice 05 , it's will be write "5" and the same for minutes.

So if i choice a date like "08:05" it's will be write "8:5" whereas i want to put "08:05"..

This is my listener of calendar :

```
public void addListenerOnTimePicker(final TextView edit_text) {

    // Récupération de l'heure courante
    final Calendar date=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Création d'un listener pour dialogue time
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listenerTime=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int heure, int minute) {             
            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, heure);
            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            // nouvelle heure dans le texteview
            edit_text.setText(Integer.toString(heure)+":"+ Integer.toString(minute));           
        }
    };

    final TimePickerDialog timePicker=new TimePickerDialog(this, listenerTime,
            date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            date.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true );

    edit_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timePicker.show();
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the hour and minute string with `%02d` using [format()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

```
String hourString = String.format("%02d", heure);
String minuteString = String.format("%02d", minute)

edit_text.setText(hourString +":"+ minuteString);
```

Comment: i put this two line into the onTimeSet() and i have : java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.String arguments

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi it was my mistake for the Exception. I update the answer.